# AWS EC2 SSH: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've configured my EC2 instance, and connected with SSH. But when I created a new Security Group with port rules I couldn't access via SSH anymore. Currently, my custom Security Group rules are:

```
SSH   0.0.0.0/0
HTTP  0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS 0.0.0.0/0
```

When I try `ssh -v -i bodruk.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-149-134-92.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` I have the following error:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-149-134-92.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.149.
134.92] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file bodruk.pem type -1
debug1: identity file bodruk.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubu
ntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000
000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA e2:13:af:e1:1b:70:f9:70:3b:cd:1d:7f:14:de:ce:90
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-149-134-92.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and ma
tches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Thiago/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: bodruk.pem
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Already tried [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/237953/amazon-ec2-ssh-failed-to-connect-bad-file-number), but doesn't work. I changed the Key Pair twice and deleted the *known_hosts* file with no success.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you give more info? Were you able to ssh in with a different security group? How is creating a new security group stops you from ssh-ing in? Is your instance associated with a keypair?

Comment: I've tried different Security Group rules, for SSH or All Trafic, but doesn't work. I'll try delete the instance and setup again.

Comment: Are you saying that it works fine with one Security Group configuration, but not with the one listed above? Security Groups will only block traffic, they won't impact the traffic itself. Did you put the rules on Inbound or Outbound (should be Inbound)?

Comment: @JohnR I deleted my old instance and generated a new one. Everything works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you telnet to the instance with the ssh port? (telnet 'ip' 'port')

If you can telnet, so the problem probably in the Key Pair or something in your computer. 
And if not, its probably something with the Security Group and network.

Comment: I deleted my old instance and generated a new one. Everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently and the funny part is my pem file was owned by root instead of my user.  When I did sudo chown user:group {pem file name}, I was able to ssh in without a problem.